# How to implement app closing/security with jQuery Mobile and Phone Gap

Tags: android, jquery, ios, jquery-mobile, cordova

I am building an app with jQuery Mobile and Phone Gap Build and I'm unsure of the best way to implement a few security features and my attempts so far have failed. This app is aimed at iOS and Android, using Phone Gap 3.4.0 and jQuery Mobile 1.4.2.

There are 2 features I need;

First, I need the app to close/reset on app suspend. Meaning, when someone leaves the app to go to the home page, changes apps, turns off the screen, etc. the app pushes you back to the login screen. So far I have tried things like:

For Android:

```
document.addEventListener("pause", onPause, false);

function onPause() {
    initialize();
    navigator.app.exitApp();
}
```

For iOS in the config.xml:

```
<preference name="exit-on-suspend" value="true" />
```

This only works sometimes. When testing on Android, the app will exit when you go home or change apps, but only for the first 10 times or so, then it stops. I assume this is due to the fact that after the app is used frequently Android stops suspending it because it is actively used?

iOS testing for this feature has been limited so far.

Second, There is a bug where when you re-open the app, and you are at the login screen, the user can press the back button and revisit pages previously visited without logging in.

To remedy this I have tried clearing all auth tokens, user names, etc. (which are only stored in variables anyway) at every possible turn and it still happens.

As I stated above, I may be going about this the wrong way and there is an easier/better way to accomplish what I want.

Comment: try to off the history so that it cannot be reversed to history page

Comment: and second way is handle the back button click event and do e.preventDefault(); after this you decide which page to go on what conditions using swich case.

Comment: and i want to know why are you using initialize() method in onPause?

Comment: @Rahul I have tried disabling the back button and that does not work, just like onPause does not work. None of the phonegap APIs work. `initialize()` is a function I created to restart the app. So it is supposed to be called when the app pauses to reset it.